# Hyper entanglement vs Maximally entangled bipartite state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Let's suppose we have hyper entanglement of two photons such as

$$|ψ\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|HH\rangle_{ab}+|VV\rangle_{ab})\otimes\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|SS\rangle_{ab}+|FF\rangle_{ab})$$

where $|H\rangle, |V\rangle$ is polarization bases, while $|S\rangle, |F\rangle$ is time-bin bases. (a,b are each party, Alice and Bob)

If we define the bases such as

$$|HS\rangle=|0\rangle$$
$$|HF\rangle=|1\rangle$$
$$|VS\rangle=|2\rangle$$
$$|VF\rangle=|3\rangle$$

we can write $|ψ\rangle$ such as

$$|ψ\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|HH\rangle_{ab}|SS\rangle_{ab}+|VV\rangle_{ab}|SS\rangle_{ab}
+|HH\rangle_{ab}|FF\rangle_{ab}+|VV\rangle_{ab}|FF\rangle_{ab})\\
= \frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle_{ab}+|11\rangle_{ab}
+|22\rangle_{ab}+|33\rangle_{ab})$$

As you can see, the last result is a maximally entangled bipartite state.

But, hyper entanglement that I defined is just a product state between two bell states.

My question is

1. What is the difference between hyper entanglement and maximally entangled state?
2. Do we call hyper entanglement as a high-dimensional entangled state?

Comment: they are two separate concepts. "Hyperentanglement" usually refers to entanglement between multiple degrees of freedom of photons/particles. It's just a particular type of entanglement. There is nothing special about it from a fundamental perspective

Comment: what result? hyperentanglement is nothing but a different term to refer to entanglement in certain experimental scenarios. It is *not* the same as "maximally entangled bipartite state". That paper doesn't even use the term.

Comment: where is that stated in the paper? (also note that you need to tag people in comments, otherwise they might not get notified by your reply and not see it)

Comment: that is saying that *this particular* hyperentangled state is maximally entangled, not that all are. It should also be expressed that it is only maximally entangled with respect to a specific bipartition (whereas the system is four-partite, so it not completely obvious which bipartition should be used for this)